# One of my third party wants WSI module enabled and other party wants it disable in magento

Tags: magento, ws-i

I am working with WS-I Compliance. In this, one of my third parties wants it to be enabled and another wants it to be disabled all the time. Important thing is they both want it for same module. So how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set module enable then You can use this condition for module if you want to put separate code.

```
if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName()=='modulename'){
      //third party code  
}else{
     //other party code
}
```